# MongoDB aggregation and grouping performance problems

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Running MongoDB 4 on Centos7 server with 16GB of RAM. Interfacing with Mongo through pymongo drivers. Currently have ~600k documents in the collection of interest.

My collection documents look like this:

```
{
    _metadata: {
        parent_name: <str_val>
        document_name: <str_val>
        datetime: <datetime object (indexed)>
        revision: <int>,
        first_name: <str>,
        last_name: <str>,
        other fields...
    }
    tag1: <val>
    tag2: <val>
    ...
}
```

There is a compound index on (_metadata.document_name, _metadata.revision, _metadata.parent_name) that requires the combination to be unique.

I am trying to run an aggregate query, grouped by exam_id and revision, such that the final documents look like this:

```
{
    parent_name: <val>
    docu_revision_pairs: [[<revision>, <document_name>], ...]
    first_name: <val>
    last_name: <val>
    <other fields from _metadata>
 }
```

And I want the documents sorted by datetime.

The query I am running is:

```
[
        {
            "$match": {},
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "$_metadata.datetime": -1
            }
        },
        {
            "$group":
            {
                "_id": {"parent_name": "$_metadata.parent_name"},
                "revision": {"$push": "$_metadata.revision"},
                "document_name": {"$push": "$_metadata.document_name"},
                "first_name": {"$first": "$_metadata.first_name"},
                "last_name": {"$first": "$_metadata.last_name"},
                "datetime": {"$first": "$_metadata.datetime"},
                <other fields from _metadata>
            }
        },
        {
            "$project":
            {
                "docu_revision_pairs": {
                    "$zip": {
                        "inputs": ["$revision", "$document_name"]
                    }
                },
                "_id": 0,
                "parent_name": "$_id.parent_name",
                "first_name": 1,
                "last_name": 1,
                "datetime": 1,
                <other fields from _metadata>: 1
            }
        },
        {
            "$skip": page_size*(page_num - 1),
        },
        {
            "$limit": page_size,
        }
    ]
```

Currently trying the "default" query which would be to do it against the entire collection, but it takes ~10-15 seconds to give me the answer, and that's before I repeat a similar query to get a count of files after the $group stage so I can paginate the results properly.

In usage, a query would run a match against the fields labeled .

Is there a better way to perform this query in the default case? Would indexing more fields or putting the metadata fields as top level help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will speed up if you make an index by metadata.datetime and sort it the way you want it in your query